# Tool to inspect desktop theme elements?

Tags: xfce, gtk, theme, gtk3

I just purchased a HiDPI monitor and though I've been able to fix the bulk of problems following the [Arch HiDPI guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI), there are still many problems to fix and I can't identify some of the desktop elements so I can theme them properly.

I've been using the program [GTKInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGTK%2B%2FInspector) to find css elements in various GTK apps so I can edit the theme, but I can't figure out how to do the same for for my xfce desktop. In GTKInspector you can drag a cross-hair (Widget Selector) over an element in a program and you can then see the GTK tree, along with the css elements so you can know what the element is called and hence you can override it in a custom gtk.css file.

[image]

I've tried launching xfce4-panel with debugging enabled, (Which is how you enable GTKInspector for a program) but it just won't work for xfce4-panel itself.

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive xfce4-panel -r &
```

Is there a way to use GTKInspector on xfce4-panel, or another tool that would identify the existing theming elements? For example, I'd like to make the icons larger in the windows list.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question but you can try to ask here : https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I've edited the question to hopefully be more descriptive.

Comment: I don't use GTKInspector at all so i don't know, that's why i give you a link to the forum of developper team of xfce. They can certainly help for what you search on xfce. You can try in the applications menu --> Settings --> Settings Manager --> Panel  --Display --> Row Size (pixels): and increment the value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The row size affects everything proportionally, so it doesn't help to get the icon size larger alone. I thought I was just missing a simple trick or  tool that was GTK-centric and not desktop specific.